# JS - Disable dropdown options based on calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to create a succession of dropdown lists, one at a time.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbus6w11/17/

I use this code to disable the options that were previously selected:

```
$("select.options").change(function () {
    $("select.options option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $("select.options option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find("option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

And this created another numeric value (varc) to be added to a total (sum) on each option (var3):

```
if (var3 == 1) {
    varc = 10;
    vartip = 'this is tip1';
} else if (var3 == 2) {
    varc = 20;
    vartip = 'this is tip2';
} else if (var3 == 3) {
    varc = 30;
    vartip = 'this is tip3';
} else if (var3 == 4) {
    varc = 40;
    vartip = 'this is tip4';
} else if (var3 == 5) {
    varc = 50;
...
};
sum += varc;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = sum;
```

However I also need to hide the options based on a complex calculation. Every time there is an option that would make the sum go over 100, I need it disabled too (before the selection is actually made)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Best regards,
João

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this turned out to be hard for you because the functions tries to do too much (too big). It's often good make small functions that do a very limited job and then return the result.

For example, all the if-statements could be in a separate function that returns what the value would be for given selected option.

Then you can use that function to check, for each of the remaining options,  what the potential sum would be if they were chosen. If that the potential sum is greater than 100, then we disable that option.

**DEMO**: I created a modified version of your code where I sketched how I would begin solve it, using the advice above. It's not complete, and I would like to see many more changes, to make the code more readable. But I think you could solve the rest of the problem from here. Tell me if you need any further help.

Other tips would be to look into **switch-statements**, instead of all the if-statements. They are made for this kind of situation. I would also look over many of the variable names, because now they are not very descriptive.

All that being said, it's a fairly complex problem, so I get how it could easily turn into a mess. *Edited to not link to external code

```js
    document.getElementById("q2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("q3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("q4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("tip1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("tip2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("tip3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("tip4").style.visibility = "hidden";

var sum = 0;

function myFunction(var1,var2,var3,var4){
document.getElementById(var1).disabled = 'disabled';
  var varTipAndVarc = getNumberAndVartipGivenOptionValue(var3);
  var varc = varTipAndVarc.varc;
  var vartip = varTipAndVarc.vartip;
  sum += varc;
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = sum;
  document.getElementById(var4).innerHTML = vartip;
  document.getElementById(var4).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById(var2).style.visibility = "visible";
};

$("select.options").change(function () {
    $("select.options option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('index', this.value);
    $("select.options option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find("option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', false);
    
    hideTooHighOptions(sum);
    });
    
function hideTooHighOptions(totalSoFar) {
    // Iterate through all the options that "live" 
  // in the enabled select elements
  // Check if their "potential sum" (if the option was selected)
  // would make the sum go over 100
  $("select:enabled > option").each((index, opt) => {
    var $opt = $(opt);
    var optionValue = $opt.attr('value');
    var potentialNumber = getNumberAndVartipGivenOptionValue(optionValue).varc;
    var potentialSum = totalSoFar + potentialNumber;
    if(potentialSum >= 100) {
      console.log(potentialNumber, totalSoFar, $opt);
      $opt.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
}
 
function getNumberAndVartipGivenOptionValue(var3) {
    var vartip;
  var varc;
    if (var3 == 1) {
    varc = 10;
    vartip = 'this is tip1';
  } else if (var3 == 2) {
    varc = 20;
    vartip = 'this is tip2';
  } else if (var3 == 3) {
    varc = 30;
    vartip = 'this is tip3';
  } else if (var3 == 4) {
    varc = 40;
    vartip = 'this is tip4';
  } else if (var3 == 5) {
    varc = 50;
    vartip = 'this is tip5';
  } else if (var3 == 6) {
    varc = 60;
    vartip = 'this is tip6';
  } else if (var3 == 7) {
    varc = 70;
    vartip = 'this is tip7';
  } else {
    varc == 0;
    vartip = 'this is tip0';
  };
  return { vartip: vartip, varc: varc };
}

function isGameOver() {
    // TODO: check if all options are disabled
  // if so, then also disable all select elements
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='result'>Total</a>s
<br><br>
<select class="options" id="q1" onchange="myFunction('q1','q2',this.value,'tip1')">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
<br><a id='tip1'>tip1</a><br>
<select class="options" id="q2" onchange="myFunction('q2','q3',this.value,'tip2')">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
<br><a id='tip2'>tip2</a><br>
<select class="options" id="q3" onchange="myFunction('q3','q4',this.value,'tip3')">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
<br><a id='tip3'>tip3</a><br>
<select class="options" id="q4" onchange="myFunction('q4','q5',this.value,'tip4')">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
</select>
<br><a id='tip4'>tip4</a><br>
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers... I can see both of them work. When I get home later I will carefully review them. I can't mark both answers as accepted, so sorry about that, I'll mark the first one. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! :) Btw, even if you can't mark both as accepted, I'm sure @Preenz would appreciate an upvote if you feel the answer was good.

Comment: I did, but they keep invisible until I have high enough reputation.

Comment: Hey. Fixed a few things all around. Can you help me finish it @jonahe ? jsfiddle.net/p70gj8ap/5 The isGameOver function and some other fixes you can recommend.

Comment: Nice, looking much better now with the variable names! I added the isGameOver,  a TODO for an edge-case (causes an exception), and suggested how you could do an automatic restart of the game, so that you can replay 5 sec after game over. http://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/p70gj8ap/9/ 

If you see something that you don't quite understand, try searching in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com). 
If you want to really test yourself you could try rewriting the whole thing. Would you do it differently now, with the new knowledge you have? (eg. Maybe go with an approach more like @Preenz?)

Comment: Thanks a lot again @jonahe . Is it possible to hide the last select with no options available instead of disabling? Preenz way is very interesting, but I don't understand two lines of what is there. My knowledge of JS is very very n00bish. Can you recommend me some good JS introductory tutorials?

Comment: Your welcome :) I liked the challenge.

Well, everything is possible ;)  You can start with thinking about the problem in pseudo-code: figure out what steps need to be taken (like the comments in the `resetGameAfterMsDelay` function does), even if you don't know how to do each step yet.  If one step in the pseudo-code is too hard or too big, try breaking it down into smaller parts.

Comment: Even if you can't figure out what each step should be, maybe you can start by writing down some aspects of the problem that you grasp: 

"I  know I need to hide the last select.. When? Only when every option in it is disabled. How can I know if every option is disabled? Well, maybe I know how I see if ONE option is disabled?".  If you go far enough you will come to a place where you actually know something, and you can start writing that part down. When you've done that, it's common that you start realizing what the next step has to be.

Comment: I you like interactive lessons then I think places like https://www.codecademy.com/ and https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery have at least some courses that are free.

You can probably find many good video tutorials on youtube as well. [This long one came up for "learn js"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XL9Ri8pO68w). But be sure to do the exercises and play around with the examples. It's one thing to understand someone else's code when they explain it bit by bit, it's another thing to be able to write it yourself.

Sorry, I will end my lecture now ;) Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152873/discussion-between-joao-gomes-and-jonahe).

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 2):

My first option to do it is to create a function that checks stuff on start and on change.

```
var checkOptions = function ()
{
  // here check the options that you want to be disabled based on your value sum
  $("select.options option").each(function () {
    // stuff
    // $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
};

$("select.options").change(function () {
  $("select.options option[value='" + $(this).data('index') + "']").prop('disabled', false);
  $(this).data('index', this.value);
  $("select.options option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).find("option[value='" + this.value + "']:not([value=''])").prop('disabled', false);
  checkOptions();
});

checkOptions();
```

my next option would be to create the select boxes using javascript, this way you can control whatever option you want to be in and out of the select boxes and cleaner stuffs. https://jsfiddle.net/mbus6w11/22/

```
var sum = 0;
var options = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Tip 1",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Tip 2",
    value: 20
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Tip 3",
    value: 30
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Tip 4",
    value: 40
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Tip 5",
    value: 50
  }
];
var onSelect = function ()
{
  var id = parseInt(this.value);
  disableOption(id);

  sum += options.find(function(item)
  {
    if (item.id == id)
    {
      return item;
    }
  }).value;

  $(".sum").html(sum);

  // Disable the select
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);

  // Do the move
  createSelect();
};
var disableOption = function (id)
{
  options = options.map(function (item)
  {
    if (item.id == id)
    {
      item.disabled = true;
    }

    return item;
  });
};
var createOptions = function (select)
{
  var newOptions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
  {
    var item = options[i];
    // here you can check what options should be in based on sum
    if ((sum + item.value) <= 100)
    {
     // Add item to available options
      newOptions.push(item);
    }
    // OR disable the item
    // {
    // item.disabled = true
    // newOptions.push(item);
    // }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++)
  {
    var optionData = newOptions[i];
    var option = $("<option></option>");
    $(option).attr("value", optionData.id);
    $(option).html(optionData.text);

    if (optionData.disabled)
    {
      $(option).attr("disabled", true);
    }

    $(select).append(option);
  }

  return newOptions.length > 0;
};
var createSelect = function ()
{
  var select = $("<select></select>");
  var hasOptions = createOptions(select);
  $(select).change(onSelect);

  // Do not create if there is no options to be displayed
  if (hasOptions)
  {
    $(".options").append(select);
  }
};

createSelect();

// HTML
// <div class="options"></div>
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you both for your answers... I can see both of them work. When I get home later I will carefully review them. I can't mark both answers as accepted, so sorry about that, I'll mark the first one. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Loved your code @Preenz . The way it creates the options using JS is really interesting. Specially when I will need to create more than 10 in some cases. The way it mixes disabled options with hidden options may confuse a little, but it works fine. The only think that is not like in my (bad) example is the tips. Tips are the text lines that show bellow each option when it is selected. Choosing the option 1 will show the text "this is tip 1" for example (in either list). Can you help me fix this?